# Are bounty points refunded if there is no answer?

Tags: support, bounty

I recently put a bounty on one of my questions, but instead of losing points when I got an answer, I lost them straight away. Is this a bug or is this meant to happen? Also if it is meant to happen, if no-body answers my question in time and the bounty stops, will I get my points back?